# PHP function to build query string from array

Tags: php

I'm looking for the name of the PHP function to build a query string from an array of key value pairs. Please note, I am looking for *the built in PHP* function to do this, not a homebrew one (that's all a google search seems to return). There is one, I just can't remember its name or find it on php.net. IIRC its name isn't that intuitive.

Answer (score 344, accepted):

You're looking for [`http_build_query()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php).

Comment: This is a quite new function, available from PHP 5.

Comment: Be careful with this function! It will omit any key-value pair where the value is NULL.
`echo  http_build_query(array("foo"=>"bar","bar"=>null))` will produce only `foo=bar`

Comment: @cb0 this works similar to form submits in a browser, an empty input field will not be included in the submitted query.

Comment: @ceejayoz Well you've known it for a long time now... Your wish has come true?

Answer (score 22):

Here's a simple php4-friendly implementation:

```
/**
* Builds an http query string.
* @param array $query  // of key value pairs to be used in the query
* @return string       // http query string.
**/
function build_http_query( $query ){

    $query_array = array();

    foreach( $query as $key => $key_value ){

        $query_array[] = urlencode( $key ) . '=' . urlencode( $key_value );

    }

    return implode( '&', $query_array );

}
```

Comment: When doing its decoding, PHP appears to percent-decode the key as well.  Possibly worth doing that here?

Comment: @cloudfeet seems reasonable to do so. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

Just as  addition to `@thatjuan`'s answer.
More compatible PHP4 version of this:

```
if (!function_exists('http_build_query')) {
    if (!defined('PHP_QUERY_RFC1738')) {
        define('PHP_QUERY_RFC1738', 1);
    }
    if (!defined('PHP_QUERY_RFC3986')) {
        define('PHP_QUERY_RFC3986', 2);
    }
    function http_build_query($query_data, $numeric_prefix = '', $arg_separator = '&', $enc_type = PHP_QUERY_RFC1738)
    {
        $data = array();
        foreach ($query_data as $key => $value) {
            if (is_numeric($key)) {
                $key = $numeric_prefix . $key;
            }
            if (is_scalar($value)) {
                $k = $enc_type == PHP_QUERY_RFC3986 ? urlencode($key) : rawurlencode($key);
                $v = $enc_type == PHP_QUERY_RFC3986 ? urlencode($value) : rawurlencode($value);
                $data[] = "$k=$v";
            } else {
                foreach ($value as $sub_k => $val) {
                    $k = "$key[$sub_k]";
                    $k = $enc_type == PHP_QUERY_RFC3986 ? urlencode($k) : rawurlencode($k);
                    $v = $enc_type == PHP_QUERY_RFC3986 ? urlencode($val) : rawurlencode($val);
                    $data[] = "$k=$v";
                }
            }
        }
        return implode($arg_separator, $data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there's no need to do that

```
GuzzleClient($config)->Request($method , $uri , [ 'json'=>[...] , 'query'=> $your_query_array ])
```

**query** will fill up your uri-query

from 2023 :D

Answer (score -3):

[Implode](http://php.net/implode) will combine an array into a string for you, but to make an SQL query out a kay/value pair you'll have to write your own function.

Comment: Tried that but it won't work. I'm trying to build an http query string which requires both the keys and the values from the array, implode can't do this.

Comment: I see, wasn't sure if you meant an SQL query string or a http query string.