# PHP array to a href value

Tags: php, arrays

I have foreach:

```
foreach( $playerHouses as $house ) :
    echo "<tr><th>$house[id]</th><td>$house[houseNumber]</td></tr>";
endforeach;
```

And I want to make button with href `a href="myfile.php?v=houses&id[]=1&id[]=2"`
(1,2) house id, foreach..

How can I do this? Now I have

```
echo "<a href='myfile.php?v=houses'>click me</a>";
```

Comment: *"One more question"* - That'd make the question too broad. Let's start by fixing one, then post another question afterwards, or edit your post to contain what you tried. Edit: this comment as per the original post https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/45904895/1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate URL with parameters from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13276226/generate-url-with-parameters-from-an-array)

Comment: The question seems to be a bit ambiguous. Do you mean that value relevant to the all of the ids should be passed in one go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Amid Kumar is almost there, but I understand OP wanted `id` to be passed as an array. Therefore his answer should be modified to

```
$url = "myfile.php?v=houses";
foreach ($playerHouses as $value)
{
    $url .= '&id[]='.$value['id'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do something like this:

```
    $url = "myfile.php?v=houses";
foreach ($playerHouses as $key => $value)
{
        $url .= '&id='.$value['id'];
}
```

Comment: As a result only last `id` will be passed.

Comment: for each loop $url will be concatenated with '&id='.$value['id'] and the finally becomes like: $url = myfile.php?v=houses&id=1&id=2&id=3&id=4

Comment: And when user clicks this link `$_GET[id]` will be 4.

Comment: Yes you are right but from the question posted above, its appear that the question owner is concerned only about string for url that my code gives, so I addressed only that. No where he mentioned about $_GET