# Collecting data with curl and sending it to a database through a form

Tags: php, arrays, database, forms, curl

I have searched everything I can think of to make this happen.  I am trying to collect data through curl, then send that data to a form which submits it to the database.  With the help of [this blog](https://davidwalsh.name/curl-post) and a pre existing product, I managed to get the following code

```
//extract data from the post
//set POST variables

$cookie_name = "drcuserid";

if(isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]))
{
$cookie = $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
}
$url = 'http://dirtrif.com/test.php';
$fields['username'] = $vbulletin->userinfo[username];
$fields['userid'] = $vbulletin->userinfo[userid];
$fields['addontitle'] = $info['title'];
$fields['addonversion'] = $info['version'];
$fields['bburl'] = $vbulletin->options[bburl];
$fields['bbtitle'] = $vbulletin->options[bbtitle];
$fields['webmasteremail'] = $vbulletin->options[webmasteremail];
$fields['cookie'] = $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];

//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

This is all uncharted territory to me, and I know it needs to be submitted to a form on `test.php` but I have no idea where to even start with it.  Every example I have come across fails to include that part or even speak of it.

I am trying to get this data submitted to my database, then from there I can manage pulling the results.  I know this is pretty demanding, but if anyone can point me in the right direction that would be awesome too.  I'm not looking to be spoon-fed I do want to learn as I evolve.

***************Added**************

Just wanted to clarify the results I'm looking for would be a way to get these variables I defined, then send them to my URL I defined, Which would submit them to my database through a form, or really any other way of sending the results to my DB.

An Example of the output I am trying to achieve would be: (DATABASE TABLES) spacing didn't work out. Hope you understand.

username  userid  addontitle  addonversion  bburl

BOB        2        Product      v1.0       somesite.com

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138527/php-curl-http-post-sample-code help?

Comment: @NigelRen no, I came across that one, I didn't see anything involving a form.  That's really the part I'm stuck at.  The contents I need in test.php is what I cant figure out, which seems would have a form within it where the variable defined in the code displayed would be submitted.

Comment: Something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13276226/generate-url-with-parameters-from-an-array to generate the data for the URL.

Comment: Again appreciate the help, but I'm failing to see how that is a form... I will update the original post.

Comment: Where is the form in your code?

Comment: read my message again

Answer (score 0):

I have read [THIS](https://html.form.guide/php-form/php-form-submit.html) which gave me more insight to working with curl.  To answer one of my questions, curl is the form (at least what I gathered) Now on to seeing if I can figure out this posting it to my DB.