# How to serialize an array (array to query string) using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, curl

I have an array of data comes from $_POST and I want to send them by curl to another page.

```
 curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_POST,true);
 curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$this->_postFields);
```

`$this->_postFields` must be an string like `a=2&b=t` right? 
so if I want to send array of data with curl to another page I must turn array to query string right?

How should I do it with PHP?

♦I tried `serialize()` and `unserialize()` but thier format is not same as query string right?
so what should I do? (I need something like `.serialize()` in jQuery that work on array not FORM)

♦ And the destination path is not under my control and the $_POST in the destination should be as $_POST not as its base64 encoded so I can't use such codes.

```
$array = array(1,2,3);
$encoded = json_encode($array);
$decoded = json_decode($encoded);
print_r($decoded);
```

Any Ideas?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Please let me know if the question is not clear or even if I should delete the question. Instead of just putting -1.thanks again.

Comment: For a PHP solution, [`http_build_query()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) might be helpful: [PHP Function To Build Query String From Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400805/php-function-to-build-query-string-from-array)

Comment: @rafaelsoufraz - thanks but the destination path is not under my control and the $_POST in the destination should be as $_POST not as its base64 encoded so I can't use such codes.` $array = array(1,2,3);
$encoded = json_encode($array);
$decoded = json_decode($encoded);
print_r($decoded);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php):

```
curl_setopt($s, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($this->_postFields));
```

> NOTICE

It looks beauty, but to use this approach be careful about  url encoding .Look next:

```
$_POST["some value"]='value1'; // " " between
$_POST["next value"]='value2'; // " " between

$url = http_build_query($_POST);

echo $url;

// OUTPUT 
some+value=value1&next+value=value2
```

Of course, after sending this $url we will not get  expected variables from $_POST.

Answer (score 5):

I think you can just do this:

```
curl_setopt($s, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($this->_postFields));
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand, you can use json.

```
$array = array(1,2,3);
$encoded = json_encode($array);
$decoded = json_decode($encoded);
print_r($decoded); //Look to it
```

If is not it, can be it:

```
$array = array(1,2,3);
echo http_build_query($array); //Look to it
```