# how to serialize array as url queryString in php?

Tags: php

I need to convert an array such as this:

```
$arr = array(1, 2, 3) ;
```

to this format:

```
arr[0]=1&arr[1]=2&arr[2]=3
```

is there any built in function in php or i must create this my self?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21172208/how-to-serialize-an-array-array-to-query-string-using-php

Comment: use http_build_query

Comment: http_build_query create this result : 0=1&1=2&2=3&3=4 but i want this result : arr[0]=1&arr[1]=2&arr[2]=3

Comment: this will help: `foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
   $queryString[] = "arr[$key]=$value";
  }
  echo implode("&",$queryString);`

Comment: thank you... i use this now ... but i was Curious for a built in func in php

Comment: actually you need a different type of query string so u can not use `http_build_query`

Comment: you could also do some tricks like `$jsonEncodedString = url_encode(json_encode($arr))` then call `"arr=$jsonEncodedString"` and in your reception script something like `json_decode($_GET['arr'])`

Comment: This has been asked many times on SO and around the internet. Please do a little research before asking.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

expected output should require key name in input data array, see below and after that use `http_build_query()` function to created query string

```
<?php 
$arr = array("arr" => array(1, 2, 3)) ; 
echo http_build_query($arr);
?>
```

encode output default

> arr%5B0%5D=1&arr%5B1%5D=2&arr%5B2%5D=3

and if you need decode output then

```
<?php 
$arr = array("arr" => array(1, 2, 3)) ; 
echo urldecode(http_build_query($arr));
?>
```

> arr[0]=1&arr[1]=2&arr[2]=3

Answer (score 0):

You can use http_build_query but with little tweak:

```
<?php 
$arr = array(1, 2, 3); 
$arr = http_build_query($arr,"arr[");
echo preg_replace('/\[\d/', '\\0]', $arr);
```

Output:

```
arr[0]=1&arr[1]=2&arr[2]=3
```

here is [demo](https://eval.in/567204)

Alternatively, you can also use:

```
<?php 
$arr = array(1, 2, 3);
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) { 
  $serialized[] = "arr[$key]=$value"; 
} 
echo implode("&",$serialized);
```

As mentioned by @Bob0t in comments, he says its faster :)

Comment: ahah, nice trick, btw a foreach loop will be more efficient on processing time :p