# How to construct url with http_build_query, but display values without variables?

Tags: php

I'm trying to generate an URL from all values of two arrays by using http_build_query:

Array 1:

```
$server = array($_GET["server"]);
```

Array 2:

```
$data = array($_GET["z_koord"],
        $_GET['x_koord'],
        $_GET["y_koord"],);
```

The code for generating URL I currently have written:

```
$server = array(''=>$_GET["server"]);
$data = array($_GET["z_koord"],
        $_GET['x_koord'],
        $_GET["y_koord"],);
$url = '.tile.openstreetmap.org';
$saite = http_build_query($server). $url ."/". http_build_query($data,'','/').".png";
```

Here's the URL made of code above:

```
=c.tile.openstreetmap.org/0=6/1=90/2=110.png
```

Here's the structure of url I'm trying to make:

```
c.tile.openstreetmap.org/6/90/110.png
```

I have reviewed some other posts about this topic like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13276226/generate-url-with-parameters-from-an-array) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400805/php-function-to-build-query-string-from-array), but those posts aren't completely useful for solving my problem.

So I hope someone with greater knowledge could show me a solution or at least a hint how to get closer to solution.

Comment: You’re using completely the wrong function to begin with. The purpose of `http_build_query` is to create a URL _query string_, and that means `name=value` pairs, separated by `&` (or a different separator character of choice.)

Comment: @misorude What could be the replacement for `http_build_query` in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [implode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php):

```
$server = $_GET["server"];
$data   = [$_GET["z_koord"],
           $_GET['x_koord'],
           $_GET["y_koord"]];
$url    = '.tile.openstreetmap.org';
$saite  = "$server/$url/" . implode('/', $data) . ".png";
```

I'm not sure about some things in this code, but the `implode()` should do the job.

Comment: `implode()` worked just fine for me. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

You are using `http_build_query` in the wrong way. You just don't need that. There are 2 options, you may use any one of them.

Use `implode()`, the simplest way to do the job.

```
$server = array(
    '' => $_GET['server']
);
$data = array(
    $_GET['z_koord'],
    $_GET['x_koord'],
    $_GET['y_koord'],
);
$url   = $server . '.tile.openstreetmap.org';
$saite = $url . '/' . implode("/", $data) . '.png';
```

Directly create the URL using the Parameters as shown here:

```
$url   = '.tile.openstreetmap.org' .;
$saite = $_GET['server'] . $url . '/' . $_GET['z_koord'] .'/'. $_GET['x_koord'] . '/'.$_GET['y_koord'] . '.png';
```

Comment: Didn't know about such ways. Thanks for the mentioned options!