# Pass multiple parameters of a row into the URL

Tags: php, html, forms, url

I want to take the data of a row into a table displayed in a page and pass it into the url, so that then I can take those parameters and put them into a form.

```
<td><a value="edit" href="add.php?Field1=<?php echo $row['Field1'];?>"></a>Aggiungi</td>
```

I've managed to get the first parameter, but I can't find the method to add more of them into that line of code.

I've tried to add another field using '&' or ';' but I can't find a solution that actually puts the second field into the url.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP function to build query string from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400805/php-function-to-build-query-string-from-array)

Comment: I really don't know how it could fit my case.

Comment: You have an array (`$row`) which you wish to put into the query string. How does it not fit your case?

Comment: and what are all the params you want to add (concatenate?)

Comment: Unrelated, that code would produce a link without text, `</a>` should be after "Aggiungi"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
<td><a value="edit" href="add.php?Field1=<?php echo $row['Field1'];?>&Field2=<?php echo $row['Field2'];?>"></a>Aggiungi</td>
```

Comment: I still see on the url only the first field

Answer (score -1):

like this friend,

&Field2=

enter code here

`<td><a value="edit" href="add.php?Field1=<?php echo $row['Field1'];?>&Field2=<?php echo`

Comment: How does this answer adds any more value that the [one already posted 10 minutes earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67334927/383904) ?